# Add Stack Exchange Moderator as a LinkedIn Job/Experience?

Tags: discussion, moderators, linkedin

I was thinking about adding being a Stack Exchange moderator to my LinkedIn Profile.

Would it be appropriate to add it as a 'job position'? Doing so would mean that I would put 'Stack Exchange Inc.' as the company which might be somewhat [misleading](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement):

> I acknowledge and agree that I am an independent volunteer moderator
>   to Stack Overflow and I am not an employee, agent or representative of
>   Stack Exchange Inc.

I saw a related question about [putting it as volunteering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274822/is-it-correct-to-add-stack-overflow-activity-as-volunteering-in-linkedin), but I feel that a 'position' is more accurate than volunteering.

**Update**: LinkedIn has the job heading as 'Experience' and has a corresponding 'Add Position' button. So it is doesn't strictly mean paid employments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So long as you make it clear in the entry that this is a volunteer position, not employment, I see no problem with including your moderator role in your LinkedIn profile.  In fact, I include it in mine, where the position title is "Community Moderator (Volunteer)".

As noted in an edit to the question, this section of the LinkedIn profile is called "Experience", not "Employment", and entries are called "positions".  I've seen other profiles where people included positions on non-profit boards of trustees, which also (for the people I know) are not paid positions.  The #1 rule is: **be clear and honest**.  That "(Volunteer)" in the larger header font on my profile is important.

LinkedIn also has a "Volunteer" section, and *usually* this is the better place to list your moderation experience.  I chose to list it as a position instead because I have an employment-related recommendation and you can't attach recommendations to volunteer positions.  Listing it as a position also allowed me to include a link to projects on SE that I've worked on (my site publishes curated collections of our content).

Answer (score 12):

I wouldn't really agree with the fact that being a SE mod counts as a job on LinkedIn.

It would be more at home in the Volunteering Experience section, rather than in the Experience section (where you add professional jobs).

> Would it be appropriate to add it as a 'job position'? Doing so would
>   mean that I would put 'Stack Exchange Inc.' as the company which might
>   be somewhat misleading:

**Yes**, it would be somewhat misleading and/or confusing for recruiters.

Answer (score 7):

It's not appropriate to represent a moderator position as a job.

Moderators are volunteers. The only paid diamonds are the community managers and developers, and moderators count as neither of those.

Being a moderator on Stack Exchange is great experience, but that's all it is. It's a good idea to put it on your résumé *because* of the valuable experience you get from it, but if it's not a job then don't put it down as one.

Comment: (+1) Nicely put, from a mod's point of view :)

Comment: [they say](http://blog.thewholebraingroup.com/linkedin-adds-volunteer-experience-section) since 2012 LinkedIn provides an option to add "Volunteer Experience & Causes" section in the profile, if this feature is still there then SE moderator position looks like a perfect fit for it

Comment: Entries in the volunteering section, unlike jobs, can't have attached recommendations.  I actually have a (job-related) recommendation resulting from my moderation, so that's relevant to me.  A job title of "Community Moderator (Volunteer)" seems clear to me.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm not familiar with LinkedIn :) If you've got a recommendation from it then it's probably worth it. If not, and all you've got is experience, I'd still leave it in the volunteering section